# How can I include categorical distributions as observed data in PyMC3?

Tags: python, pymc3, probability-theory

I have a dataset where each observation is basically a series of noisy measurements and one of the measurements contains signal.

Raw observed data *y*:

```
[[  1.93542253e-01   1.39657327e-04   7.53918636e-01   5.23994535e-02]
 [  6.44964587e-02   8.50087384e-01   1.09894665e-02   7.44266910e-02]
 [  1.68387463e-02   5.38121456e-01   6.98554551e-02   3.75184342e-01]
 ..., 
 [  5.79786789e-01   1.47417427e-02   3.15395731e-01   9.00757372e-02]
 [  8.66796124e-02   8.66999904e-02   4.47848127e-02   7.81835584e-01]
 [  8.18765043e-01   3.23448859e-03   5.61247840e-04   1.77439220e-01]]
```

I want to put each observation into an appropriate cluster based on this measurement data.  For example the first datapoint above is drawn from the third column and the second datapoint above is drawn from the second column.  If I sample from the known original distribution and provide those samples to the model as inputs to the Categorical I can get back the original distribution.

Sampled from original data *y_choice*:

```
[ 2.  3.  3.  1.  2.  2.  2.  2.  3.  3.  1.  2.  3.  0.  2.  0.  3.  1.
  3.  0.  2.  0.  3.  0.  2.  0.  1.  0.  3.  0.  2.  0.  0.  0.  3.  0.
  2.  0.  0.  3.  3.  1. ...
```

However this seems like I'm losing information because my choice sampler is outside the PyMC model.  How can I supply the actual observed data *y* directly into the model?  I'm guessing it has something to do with another model parameter based on the Dirichlet, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how that works.

The sample code I'm operating from is below.  I want to be able to supply *y* to the model and get the *true_probs* back out, but I've only managed to get it to work with *y_choice* so far.

```
import numpy as np
from pymc3 import *
import pymc3 as pm
import pandas as pd
print 'pymc3 version: ' + pm.__version__


def generate_noisy_observations():
    y = np.ones((sample_size,k))
    for i in range(sample_size):
        #print("Iteration %d" % i)
        true_category = np.random.choice(k, size=1, p=true_probs)
        true_distribution = np.zeros(k)
        true_distribution[true_category] = 1
        noise_distribution = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(k))

        noise = np.random.normal(0,1,k)

        distribution_weights = [0.9, 0.1]
        raw_distribution = (true_distribution*distribution_weights[0] + noise**2*distribution_weights[1] )/\       (np.sum(true_distribution*distribution_weights[0])+np.sum(noise**2*distribution_weights[1]))
        y[i] = raw_distribution
return y

def generate_choices_from_noisy_observations(y):
    y_choice = np.ones(sample_size)
    for i in range(sample_size):
        y_choice[i] = np.random.choice(k, size=1, p=y[i])
    return y_choice

sample_size = 1000

true_probs = [0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4]
k = len(true_probs)


y = generate_noisy_observations()

y_choice = generate_choices_from_noisy_observations(y)

with pm.Model() as multinom_test:
    probs = pm.Dirichlet('a', a=np.ones(k))
    #data = Categorical('data',p = probs, observed = y)
    data = Categorical('data',p = probs, observed = y_choice)
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    trace = pm.sample(50000, pm.Metropolis())

pm.traceplot(trace[500:])
```